# Database design - storing different assets (same table vs. diff tables)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm curious if there is a preferred method for storing assets in a database, that is, the path to the files (I'll be using postgres if that matters). I'll have PDFs, Videos, and audio files.

Should I create a single table and have a 'type' field, or does it make more sense to create a pdfs table, videos table and audio table?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "store assets in a DB"? Do you want to store their data? Do you want to store their URLs (pointing to something like S3)?

Comment: The latter. It would just store the path to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common question when it comes to designing database, and there's no one-size-fits-all answer. It really depends on which of the two setups is going to be most useful to you. Or, which setup is going to cause you the *least* problems.

Logically, do you expect to deal with each resource differently? Or do you expect to treat them largely as subtle variants of the same type of thing? For example, are there relations or constraints in your data model which refer to one specific type (e.g. resumes.pdf_file_id would be specifically for a PDF file, and having it potentially be an mp3 wouldn't be very helpful). If yes, I'd go with separate tables.

On the other hand, if you want to be able to see all the attachments a user has uploaded, it would be easiest to just query a single table, e.g. `SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE user_id=?`, instead of dealing with selecting from three separate tables.

There are middle-ground options, though. You could have the separate tables, but link them all to an `attachments` table which stores the S3 URL. Or you could use database-level inheritance to treat them as both separate and unified tables (this solution often *seems* perfect, but I wouldn't recommend it). Ultimately, the best choice depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful.